# Short story about self-driving car suddenly switching to manual causing a massive pile-up

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read this in a science magazine, probably early 2010s, about one page.

A man is in his car on the highway filled with self-driving cars travelling at high speeds (much faster than modern-day highway speeds). The car suddenly switches to manual mode due to a government regulation that requires the manual controls to be checked regularly. Due to the high speeds the man quickly loses control and crashes, and since the highway is full this turns into a massive pile-up (I remember there being a mention of instantaneously increasing car insurance premiums at this point). The story ended with the man's last thoughts before he died in the crash.